# How to compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t^{s+1}} dt $?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, trigonometry

How to compute $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t^{s+1}}\;\text dt$ ?

Here, the real part of the complex number $s$ is negative and greater than $-1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Computing $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \cfrac{e^{\varepsilon it}}{t^{s-1}}dt$ for $\varepsilon \in \left\{-1,1\right\}$? Series?

Comment: I have run Mathematica to obtain $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t^{s+1}} dt=-\Gamma(-s) \sin \frac{s\pi}2$, and tried computing $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{it}}{t^{s+1}}dt$ as we do when computing $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$. But I lost the way.

Comment: Integrate $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{s+1}}$ around a closed quarter-circle in the first quadrant of the complex plane that is indented at the origin.  And $- 1 < \text{Re}(s) < 1$.

Answer (score 16):

Using the definition of $\Gamma$-function from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), prove:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-a t}\,t^{s-1}\,dt=\Gamma(s)\,a^{-s},$$
then represent
$$\sin t=\frac{e^{i t}-e^{-i t}}{2\,i}.$$

Comment: Many thanks! Does the above equality hold even when $a$ is a complex number?

Comment: In general it holds for $\text{Re}(a) >0$.  But integrating around the contour I suggested above will also show it holds for $a$ purely imaginary.

Comment: I'm doing the contour integral as you suggested. Many thanks!