# Catalan constant's integral representation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, catalans-constant

Catalan constant is known to have a rich source of integral identities, here is the formula I found:
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))}{x} \,dx \ =2G.$$
This can be proved by analyzing the function and using the identity:
$$ \frac{2G}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}=\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n-1)^{4n-1}}{(4n-3)^{2n-1}(4n+1)^{2n}}\right).$$
Is there any "neat" way to prove the formula directly without using the identity? It's really hard for me to prove the identity.
**Update**
I found my own way to prove this integral indentity:
Using Fourier series of triangle wave, with a little change in the coefficient, I got this equation:
$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{(2n+1)^{2}}$$
Divide both sides by $x$ and integrate:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))}{x}dx=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^{2}}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{x}dx$$
Using the fact that $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{x}dx=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we got:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))}{x}dx=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^{2}}=2G$$

Answer (score 9):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\int_{-N\pi}^{(N+1)\pi} \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \left( \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{x + n \pi} \right) \arcsin(\sin x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Using the identity $ \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{x + n \pi} = \frac{1}{\sin x}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Substituting $t=\tan(x/2)$, the last integral reduces to

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sec^2(x/2)}{2\tan(x/2)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \int_{0}^{1} t^{2n} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \\
&= 2G.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach if you are happy to use results which I will quote and give links to their proofs elsewhere on this site. I agree it is not as self-contained as @Sangchul Lee's answer, so it really depends on what you are after.

I will make use of three results. They are:

1. The Maclaurin series expansion for the [inverse sine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105024/finding-the-power-series-of-arcsin-x) of
   $$\arcsin (x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n + 1}}{2^{2n} (2n + 1)} \binom{2n}{n}, \quad |x| \leqslant 1.$$
2. The [improper integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172080/int-0-infty-frac-sin2n1xx-mathrm-dx-evaluate-integral)
   $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1}(x)}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n + 1}} \binom{2n}{n}.$$
   Here $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$
3. A [series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056291/conjecture-sum-limits-n-0-infty2n-choose-n22-4n-fracn6n-12n/3057181#3057181) involving the square of the central binomial coefficient
   $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{1}{2^{4n}(2n + 1)} = \frac{4\mathbf{G}}{\pi}.$$

If $x$ is replaced with $\sin x$ in the first result we have
$$\arcsin(\sin x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1} x}{2^{2n}(2n + 1)} \binom{2n}{n}, \quad \text{for all $x$}.$$

**The interchange made between the summation and the integration signs based on invoking Fubini's theorem in this case is not permissible. A salvaged answer using a regularisation suggested by @Sangchul Lee is given in the Update Answer below.**

Replacing this term in our integral, after interchanging the summation and integration signs which is permissible due to $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{Fubini's theorem}}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{x} \, dx &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n + 1)} \binom{2n}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1} x}{x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^2 \frac{1}{2^{4n}(2n + 1)} \qquad \text{(from the second result)}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{4 \mathbf{G}}{\pi} = 2\mathbf{G}, \qquad \text{(from the third result)}
\end{align*}
as required to show.

**Updated Answer**

Here is a salvaged answer based on a regularisation of the demoninator $x$ by $x^{1 + s}$ for $0 < s < 1$.

Since
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{x^{1+s}}\right|\,\mathrm{d}x < \infty,$$
the interchange between the summation and the integration signs is justified by Fubini's theorem. Thus
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arcsin(\sin x)}{x} \, dx =  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n + 1)} \binom{2n}{n} \lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1} x}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx.$$

For the integral that has appeared, using
$$\sin^{2n+1}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1} \sin\left((2k+1)x\right),$$
one has
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1}(x)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left((2k+1)x\right)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1} (2k + 1)^s\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx.
\end{align*}
Note in the second line a substitution of $(2k + 1)x \mapsto x$ has been made. A value for the integral that has appeared can be found (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401308/how-to-compute-int-0-infty-frac-sin-tts1-dt?noredirect=1)). It is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx = -\Gamma(-s) \sin \left (\frac{s\pi}{2} \right ), \quad 0 < s < 1.$$
One therefore has
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1}(x)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx = -\Gamma (-s) \sin \left (\frac{s \pi}{2} \right ) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1} (2k + 1)^s.$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
\lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1}(x)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx &= \lim_{s \to 0^+} \left [-\Gamma (-s) \sin \left (\frac{s \pi}{2} \right ) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1} (2k + 1)^s \right ]\\
&= \lim_{s \to 0^+} \left (-\Gamma (-s) \sin \left (\frac{s\pi}{2} \right ) \right ) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{4^n} \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1} \lim_{s \to 0^+} (2k + 1)^s.
\end{align*}
Since $k = 0,1,2,\ldots$, then $\lim_{s \to 0^+} (2k + 1)^s = 1$ and it can be shown that
$$\lim_{s \to 0^+} \left (-\Gamma (-s) \sin \left (\frac{s\pi}{2} \right ) \right ) = \frac{\pi}{2},$$
giving
$$\lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1}(x)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n + 1}} \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1}.$$
The binomial sum can be found using a [telescoping trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172080/int-0-infty-frac-sin2n1xx-mathrm-dx-evaluate-integral/172090#172090). The result is:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k \binom{2n+1}{n+k+1} = \binom{2n}{n}.$$
So finally
$$\lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n + 1}(x)}{x^{1 + s}} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n + 1}} \binom{2n}{n},$$
which is a regularised version of the second result I initially gave and the final result for the integral then follows as before.

Okay, I believe that salvages my initial result but it is hardly straight forward nor a "neat" way of proving your result.

*Conclusion*

Stick with @Sangchul Lee's solution.

Comment: One "minor" issue: You can't apply the Fubini's theorem directly to your case, since $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{x}\right|\,\mathrm{d}x=+\infty.$$ I think a suitable regularization will allow us to avoid this issue, but still, we need some extra work to rigorously justify that interchanging.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, yes are indeed correct and I can see that now and makes it more than a "minor" issue. I will have to see if such an approach can be "saved" or not.

Comment: I can see that regularizing the denominator $x$ by $x^{1+s}$ for $0<s<1$ allows to save your approach, with a bit of work. Perhaps other types of regularizations might work as well, but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @SangchulLee I believe I have salvaged my answer based on your suggested regularisation. **Conclusion**: Your answer is far superior.

Comment: Actually I found a shorter workaround. The trick is that each of the integrals appearing in $$\int_{0}^{x}\arcsin(\sin(t))\,\mathrm{d}t=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{x}\sin^{2n+1}t\,\mathrm{d}t$$ are all non-negative for $x\geq 0$, and so, we can apply the Tonelli's theorem to get $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\int_{0}^{x}\arcsin(\sin(t))\,\mathrm{d}t\biggr)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\int_{0}^{x}\sin^{2n+1}t\,\mathrm{d}t\biggr)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}.$$ Now perform integration by parts!

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention that your approach is interesting!

Comment: Hi. Thank you all for helping me. I found this formula while learning the zig zag function. I managed to solve it by turning the integral into a infinite sum( since the arcsin(sin(x)) function can be broken apart ) but I stuck there. Then I found a [paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL15/Tzermias/tzermias2.pdf) which helped me get the answer immediately but I didn't understand the proof well. In addition, I don't know  many advanced tools( I'm just a student ) but I'll try to learn them one by one.

Comment: @SangchulLee  Is it always true that $\lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{1+s}} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, \mathrm dx$ if $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, \mathrm dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral?

Comment: @RandomVariable, With some extra condition on $f$, such as $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(x^{\varepsilon})$ as $x\to0^+$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, will guarantee that.

Comment: @SangchulLee May I ask why that additional condition is needed?  I was assuming that it ensures the integral converges uniformly on $[0, \delta]$ for some $\delta >0$, but I don't know if that's true.

Comment: @RandomVariable Indeed the extra condition I mentioned is needed to guarantee that the regularized integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^{1+s}}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges for $s\in[0,\delta]$ for some $\delta > 0$. It would be interesting to explore the question as to whether the existence of this regularized integral near $s=0$ alone is enough to guarantee the Abelian-theorem-type result.

Comment: @RandomVariable, The convergence of the improper integral might possibly be uniform, but the argument I am considering does not use that fact. Frankly speaking, I haven't thought about that direction.